# React styled components pass image url prop to display different image per page?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

So I made this component with a background image, but I need to pass in the image URL dynamically so I don't have to manually copy and paste the entire code per each page.

Here is my current method for adding the image to my component

```
 import Photo from './images/photo-1.jpg'

 const Section = styled.section`
   background: url(${Photo}) center;
  `
```

My issue is if I want to reuse this component, I don't see how I can pass in a custom image value based on the page I am on?

I tried this, but it says image is undefined.

```
const Component = ({image}) => {
return (
 <Section image={image}></Section>
}
```

Then in my pages folder, I pass it like this

```
 import Photo from './images/photo-1.jpg'

 <Component image={Photo} />
```

But for some reason, it isn't working

So example, if I am on the `home` page I want `photo-1.jpg` to display. But if I am on the `About` page I want `photo-2.jpg` to display.

So I wanna reuse the `<Component image={PhotoTwo} />` infinitely and just pass in whatever background image I need to use based on my page.

Any idea why it says `image` is undefined?

Here's my code normally with one image.

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import Photo from './images/photo-1.jpg'

 const Section = styled.section`
   background: url(${Photo}) center;
  `

 const Component = () => {
 return (
  <Section>My Section</Section>
 }
```

Then in my Home page I just add it normally like this

```
    const Home = () => {
      return (
        <>
          <Component />
        </>
      );
    };

    export default Home;
```

And this shows my Photo image fine if I only have one image. But what if I want to reuse this component, but pass in a different image? How would I do that?

Comment: Can you include more details? Ex. your full code?

Comment: what else do you need? the only thing that display the background image is the ` background: url(${Photo}) center;` so that works fine with only one image. But if I want to pass an image URL dynamically, then that's when I have issues

Comment: For example, what's `styled.section`?

Comment: I added a block below. It's just my styled component showing the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Styled `Section` you are importing props in the wrong way.

If you are passing image props to Styled `Section`,

```js
<Section image={image}></Section>
```

Inside Styled `Section` you will receive the props like,

```js
const Section = styled.section`
   background: url(${(props) => props.image || 'fallback-image.jpg' }) center;
  `
```

Reference:

1. https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#passed-props